# How to rewrite URL in .htaccess, whats wrong here

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

think the user enter

```
localhost/app/public/anything/anything/index/php/id/5
```

then id like to change it to the

```
localhost/app/public/index.php?id=5
```

the expression that i wrote is this

`RewriteRule ^index/php/id/([0-9]+)$ http://localhost/saecms/public/index.php?id=$1 [L]`

but it doesn't work, whats wrong here? thank you

Comment: I smell incoming answer from _anubhava_, one of the only 3 users with gold badge in `.htaccess` so I'm not posting mine

Comment: @DeDee That was quite funny :)

Comment: @DeDee: Feel free to post an answer to provide me pleasure of upvoting your answer.

Comment: @anubhava I'd rather see if I could learn from you, go for it :)

Comment: man, i tried many expression but i cant solve it, i'm new with this , i don't know why when i use / this in the regex nothing work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `/app/public/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/public/

RewriteRule (?:^|/)index.php/id/(\d+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: there is another problem here that i cant fix it, sorry to ask.
the css file and some images doesn't load, the path is 
localhost/app/public/something/something/news/php/id/js/jquery.js
how can i fix this??

Comment: That might be due to your use of relative paths. How are those css/js being included in your HTML?

Comment: <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
all of the css file are included like this

Comment: ok so you're including it as `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` and actual working path is `http://localhost/app/public/css/bootstrap.min.css` ?

Comment: by adding this tag, everything work well now 
`<base href="http://localhost/app/public/" target="_blanck">`
thanks you for help.